# Xcode 6 So slow that I use Microsoft Words instead(cpu usage)

Tags: xcode, performance, swift, sprite-kit, cpu-usage

I am busy with a big project(game) and my GameScene file is getting bigger and bigger.
however, this should not be the reason that xcode uses 100+ % of CPU..

My Xcode(6.1.1) is slowed so much down that I have to copy paste my gamescene file into a microsoft words file, add/change the code I want, than copy paste back into Xcode.

When I try to select code/scroll threw code/delete code/add code the CPU usage of my Imac goes up to 100% and xcode freezes for a few seconds(every time).

this is very frustating and I would like to know how I can fix this.

This Did not help:

-restart iMac

-restart Xcode

-delete xcworkspace file

-delete xcuserdata map

-turn off auto completion xcode

-disable live issues

-disable source control

-deleted derrived data

Comment: what version do you have? is it the latest?

Comment: delete derived data, let it complete indexing

Comment: I deleted derrived data, did not help.

Comment: What about closing the project you work on, create a new project, restart xcode (to be sure the previous project doesn't have anything in memory), then see if the performance is better. Typically indexing will grind Xcode to a halt sometimes, so it may depend on how many source files/libraries you've added to the project.

Comment: I have not added any libraries but I have a lot of png files, can that be the problem? that would be weird guessing xCode is not using any png files when I am coding the gamescene file?

Comment: Sourcekitservice is using also high % of cpu, what is this proces and can I quit it and go further with coding at xcode?